# Printing * pattern in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to print a pattern like this

```
*******
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*******
```

In this it should look like an empty box.
but somehow I am not getting even closer

I coded this so far

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j<=7;j++)
    {
        if(j==1||j==7)
        printf("*");
        else printf(" ");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

and my output is

```
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
```

it will be good to have for loop only

Comment: You're almost there, I think! Only need to get the top and bottom rows to print stars everywhere instead of only at the beginning at the end.

Comment: I would replace 'i' with 'y' and 'j' with 'x' to make the code more readable.  'i' and 'j' can easily be confused at a glance and 'x' and 'y' are more typical for row/column coordinates.

Comment: Since you seem to be new to programming I want to give another hint: *Don't* write constants literally at the place where they are used (here, the `7`). Instead, introduce **named constants** (`static const int size = 7`) and use this in the loops. Why? It's simple: If you want to **change** the size (let's say to 10), you don't have to look at the code where it is used and replace 7 to 10 and forget one occurrence (or replace another 7 which isn't the size). Also, the code is more **readable**: Your 7 has a meaning which you didn't write *in words*. If you write `size`, it has a meaning.

Comment: as a rule of thumb it is a good idea to use variable names that give info to the reader e.g. row instead of i and col instead of j.

Answer (score 11):

```
if(j==1||j==7)
printf("*");
else printf(" ");
```

This logic works for all rows except first and last one. So you have to consider row value and make special check for first and last rows. These two do not have spaces.

[Assuming it's a homework, I'm giving just a hint. You almost have done it, above hint should be enough to get this working.]

Comment: +1 for not just vomiting out trivial code, but instead giving an answer that will actually HELP the OP.

Answer (score 6):

Your `if` condition simply needs to be:

```
if (i==1 || i==7 || j==1 || j==7)
```

That is, you need to check whether you're on either the first or last rows as well as either the first or last columns, and then print a `*`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to behave differently during first and last row:

```
int W = 7, H = 7;
for(int i=0;i<=H;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<=W;j++)
  {
     // if row is the first or row is the last or column is the first of column is the last
     if (i == 0 || i == H-1 || j == 0 || j == W-1)
       printf("*");
     else printf(" ");
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow, spoiling homework assignments for everybody! :)

Comment: My personal policy about homework is that I'm not going to help if you are lazy, this is not the case. In addition I don't see any homework tag, how would you know it is homework? Just by personal guess?

Comment: You help better if you explain what should be changed instead of just posting working code at which one doesn't even have to look again.

Comment: @Jack A good programmer can learn coding from good programmer like you ! I believe if one explain the code logically a bit then its helpful I have been teacher and I frequently have to  answer as you given.

Comment: What shall I actually explain? The condition is self explanatory, I mean are we talking about explaining "if row is the first or row is the last or column is the first of column is the last"? That is what is implicitly done by using two constants instead that magic numbers. I guess the OP already knows about OR and about indices otherwise we wouldn't see a single line of code.

Comment: @leemes: if he won't look at the code again then it's his fault and he'll pay the consequences in the future. I'm not here to force people  to learn, I'm here to help people. If someone wants just to copy and paste code then it's his business, nothing I should care about. I gave an answer that explains how and why if you spend time to read it, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.  The problem is in this line:

```
    if(j==1||j==7)
```

Change it so that it also takes into account the top and bottom rows.

Good luck

Comment: +1 for not just hammering out some code but instead giving the OP a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This function will work fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printBox(int width, int height) {
    if (width < 2 or height < 1) return;
    for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
        if (i == 1 or i == height) {
            std::string o(width, '*');
            std::cout << o << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::string o(width-2, ' ');
            o = '*' + o + '*';
            std::cout << o << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used as:

```
printBox(2, 2);
```

which prints:

```
**
**
```

Or as:

```
printBox(6, 4);
```

which prints:

```
******
*    *
*    *
******
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not expert in programming, I came up with this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k,n;

    printf("Enter no of rows : \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0 || i == (n-1))
        {
            for(j=0; j <n-1; j++)
                printf("*");
        }              
        else
        {
            for(k=0; k<n; k++)
            {
                if (k == 0 || k == (n-2))
                    printf("*");
                else
                    printf(" ");
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you ataravati for the indentation.

Comment: This is nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int j=1;j<=7;j++)
{
    if(j==1||j==7)
        printf("*******\n");
    else
        printf("*     *\n");
}

printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating all lines equally and ignoring the fact that the first and last line must be handled differently. You need something like

```
if (i == 1 || i == 7)
{
    for (j=1;j<7;j++) printf("*");
    printf("\n");
}
else { /* your routine */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j<=7;j++)
    {
        if(j == 1 || j == 7)
           printf("*");
        else if (i == 1 || i == 7 ) //added this check
             printf ("*");
        else printf(" ");
    }



    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2AZaXl%249)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a nested loop. Because you've two options in between their, you'll need two nested loops. One for spaces and one for the filling '*' in iteration 1 and 7 (0 and 6).

Print the line 1 and 7 with a '*' filling the boundary stars.
Using

```
if (i == 0 || i == 7)  // in-case you're initializing i with 0
    // loop for printf ("*");
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you need to handle first and last row. One way to build each line is to make use of one of string constructors, so you don't need to write the inner loop.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int height = 7, width = 7;

    for( int i=0; i<height; i++ )
    {
        char c = (i == 0 || i == height-1) ? '*' : ' ';
        string line(width, c);
        line[0] = line[width-1] = '*';
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

main()
{
      int Width;
      char MyChar;
      int LCV;    //Loop control
      int LCVC, LCVR;    //Loop control for LCVC=Columns LCVR=Rows

      cout<<"\nEnter Width: "; cin>>Width;
      cout<<"\nEnter a Character: "; cin>>MyChar;

      for (LCV=1;LCV<=Width;LCV++)
      {cout<<MyChar;}
      cout<<endl;
      for(LCVC=1;LCVC<=Width;LCVC++)
      { cout<<MyChar<<setw(Width-1)<<MyChar<<endl;

      }
      for (LCV=1;LCV<=Width;LCV++)
      {cout<<MyChar;}
      cout<<endl;
      system("pause");
}

/*
Enter Width: 6

Enter a Character: #
######
#    #
#    #
#    #
#    #
#    #
#    #
######
Press any key to continue . . .
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Print this pattern 
enter a number=each number for example 23517
**

---

---

*

---

Then
              **
             ***
          *****
                 *
       *******
then
**        *
***      *
*****   *

---

and
              *
              *
              *
              *
              *

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It appears that your answer underwent some incorrect formatting. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a simple solution. You can keep it very simple rather than using char array pointers that you used.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int rows = 7;
    for(int i = 1; i<=rows;i++){
        if(i == 1 || i == rows){
            cout<<"*******"<<endl;
        }else{
            cout<<"*     *"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}   // This code outputs 7 rows with 7 characters in 1st and 7 line each and 1 each character at the start and last position of the remaining rows
```

But if you want a custom number of rows, you can try out the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int rows;
    cout<<"Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin>>rows;  // gets input rows from the user

    for(int i = 1; i<=rows;i++){
        if(i == 1 || i == rows){
            cout<<"*******"<<endl;
        }else{
            cout<<"*     *"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add:

```
    `if(i==0 || i==6)
    {
    cout<<"*";
    }`
```